# Why jenkins can not perform certain names of jmx?

Tags: jenkins, ant, jmeter

1.It can't perform when my script name is lotteryOnline:
[image]

2.But changed to other names (such as game), BUILD SUCCESSFUL：
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your JMeter test execution for this `lotteryOnline` test plan has failed. The reason of failure you can see in the *jmeter.log* file. If you don't see the log file you can add `jmeterlogfile` parameter to `jmeter` Ant task like:

```
<jmeter
     jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
     testplan ="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
     resultlog="${testpath}/${test}.jtl"
     jmeterlogfile="/path/to/jmeter.log"> <!-- add this line to enable logging-->
```

References:

- [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Jmeter.log shows JMeter test execution has been interrupted.But,the same script runs fine on my local with Windows, in UI and Non GUI mode.

Comment: Do you provide enough Java Heap space for Ant? JMeter might fall with out of memory issue, to overcome it you need to increase JVM heap size by passing `<jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/>` value to the build.xml file or setting `ANT_OPTS=-Xmx512M` environment variable (amend this `512M` default setting to be ~80% of your total physical RAM) . Also make sure you're following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article

Comment: OK，I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a file, which is called `game.itl`. The parameter where you supply `game` is used to pick that file, as it seems.